# Ensure field is unique for another field in Django Models

Tags: django, django-models, django-constraints

I want a field in a model to be unique based on another field, but not vice versa.

For example:

```
class Shipment(models.Model):

    supplier = models.ForeignKey("Supplier", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='shipments')
    external_id = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

I want that two shipments cannot have same supplier and same external_id, but can have same external_id and different supplier, or same supplier and different external_id.

I know unique_together. But it makes a supplier to only have one external_id. However, I want a supplier to have multiple external_ids while all of them are unique.

I can check this constraint in save() method, but I want a database constraint, or something wiser.

Comment: Check it, where you are saving `Shipment`: 
`if Shipment.objects.filter(supplier_id=supplier_id, external_id=external_id).exists(): raise error here`

Comment: Thanks, but it is like checking it in save() method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [UniqueConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint)?

```
class Shipment(models.Model):
    supplier = models.ForeignKey("Supplier", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='shipments')
    external_id = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['supplier', 'external_id'], name='unique_shipment')]
```

Comment: As I know it is like unique_together behavior. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Sort of, but according to the documentation unique_together is like going to be deprecated, so it's suggested to use UniqueConstraint instead. UniqueConstraint also has more funcionality, like you can set a condition passing a Q object as a parameter.

Comment: Actually that's what I'm looking for. A constraint set with Q object. But I don't know how.

Comment: Anyway I don't understand how unique_together or UniqueConstraint aren't being helpful in your case, how are you writing your code when you're using them? do you have any error message to see? also I guess the external_id shouldn't never be blank

Comment: unique_together  and UniqueConstraint make a supplier have only one external_id. But I want a supplier to have many shipment with different external_id, but all of them be unique. And no, external_id can be blank.

Comment: External_id CAN be blank? But I don't see that you use blank=True for the external_id field.

Comment: Yes, but I forgot to write it here.

Comment: When a charfield is blank=True, what django does is store an empty string in the database, maybe django is finding duplicates because there are many suppliers with a shipment with the external_id with a empty string value ('"") so when you try to add another shipment with a blank external_id for the same supplier it already exists for django

Comment: You're right, but I'm handling it. I save """ value as None.